# How to pass 'y' or 'n' to shell script only when required from Java program?

Tags: java, shell

I have a java code which calls shell script. Sometimes my script asks for y or n, I looked up online and found:

```
yes y| path/to/script/script.sh
```

I assume above will also work fine when:

```
yes y| path/to/script/script.sh parameters_to_script.
```

Below is snippet of my code:

```
String script_path_parameters = "yes y| path/to/script/script.sh parameters_to_script ";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script_path_parameters);
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
while((line = b.readLine())!=null){
 system.out.println(line); // This will print whatever script is doing.
}
```

My script went in endless loop by priniting on console :

```
yes y| path/to/script/script.sh parameters_to_script 
y| path/to/script/script.sh parameters_to_script 
y| path/to/script/script.sh parameters_to_script 
y| path/to/script/script.sh parameters_to_script 
y| path/to/script/script.sh parameters_to_script
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write 'y' to stdin of the process.

So something like that.

```
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(p.getInputStream());
    writer.println("y");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Java port of [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) tool. For instance, using [expectj](http://expectj.sourceforge.net):

```
ExpectJ expectinator = new ExpectJ(5);
Spawn shell = expectinator.spawn("/bin/sh");
shell.send("path/to/script/script.sh params\n");
shell.expect("<script text asking to answer yes or no>");
shell.send("y\n");
```

Basically, it scripts interaction with the shell interpreter.